# Error loading property file Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-resources-plugin

i get this error from eclipse marker , when i try to load a filter file from pom.xml.
it display the message below.

```
 Error loading property file 'src/main/filters/filter.properties' (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources:default-resources:process-resources)
```

pom.xml:

```
 <execution>
        <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <filters>
                <filter>src/main/filters/filter.properties</filter>
            </filters>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

is that  a  bug  ?

Comment: You usually get that error because the file doesn't exist.  Have you verified that `src/main/filters/filter.properties` is actually there?

Comment: yes there are unfortunately

Comment: What happens if you put `${basedir}/src/main/filters/filter.properties`?  Or, does the filter file belong to a parent project by chance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the solution is put `${basedir}/src/main/filters/filter.properties` instead of `src/main/filters/filter.properties`

```
<execution>
        <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <filters>
                <filter>${basedir}/src/main/filters/filter.properties</filter>
            </filters>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```