# How to ignore missing filter file error on pom.xml in Eclipse when using resource filtering?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3, maven-resources-plugin

I have a multi-module project like this:

```
parent
|
+-- childA
|   +-- src/main/resources/application.properties
|
+-- childB
    +-- src/main/resources/application.properties
    +-- src/main/filters/filter.properties
```

I am filtering the `application.properties` in both childA and childB using the `filter.properties` in childB.

I followed [this strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1528295/1176178) to attach the filter file to childB's artifact and then unpack it on childA's target:

```
childA/target/filters/filter.properties
```

childA has resource filtering like this:

```
<build>
  <filters>
    <filter>target/filters/filter.properties</filter>
  </filters>
</build>
```

Eclipse is flagging an error on `childA/pom.xml`:

> Error loading property file
>   'parent\childA\target\filters\filter.properties'
>   (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:copy-resources:default-resources:process-resources)

The filter file is available when I build the app, so I'm not concerned there.

**How can I update the pom.xml of childA to permanently ignore this error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue went away after upgrading from Eclipse Luna to Neon.

Answer (score 0):

You have taken that `filter.properties` file from your **target** folder. It is not the right way. You should consider it from your 
`src/main/filters/filter.properties` file.

```
<filters>
    <filter>${basedir}/src/main/filters/filter.properties</filter>
</filters>
```

For more, you can go through this tutorial: [Error loading property file Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477450/error-loading-property-file-maven)

### UPDATE#2:

From my side, you can keep the properties file in your parent. Then give the reference on both ChildA and childB using the following filter. Hopefully it will work.

```
<filters>
    <filter>${basedir}/src/main/filters/filter.properties</filter>
</filters>
```

### UPDATE#3:

Stephen conolly has told in his post like below:

> Think about what happens when your project is listed as a dependency.
>   If you had specified its dependencies by using a mojo to pull those
>   from a .properties file on disk, Maven has no way to replicate that
>   when your dependency has been pulled from the Maven repository. So
>   Maven would be unable to determine the dependencies. Thus it could
>   never work.
>
> What you could do, is use an external system (e.g. ANT) to generate
>   the pom.xml from a template with the versions replaced into that file.
>   And then use the instantiated template to build.

**Resource Link:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/14727072

Similar question is asked here: [Maven2 property that indicates the parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012402/maven2-property-that-indicates-the-parent-directory)

Dennis Lundbarg said this issue as anti-pattern in [this post](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Relative-path-to-parent-directory-at-multi-module-maven-project-td4611798.html):

> Referencing a files in another module using relative paths is an 
>   anti-pattern. One reason for this is that it will break your build if 
>   you are using a build server, like Jenkins. The build server will
>   check  out each module into a separate folder, which is not in the
>   same folder  structure that your project is using.
>
> The best practice way of sharing resources like configuration files is
>   storing them in an archive that is deployed to your repository. When 
>   that is done you can either use it as a dependency, making the
>   resources  available on the class path, or use the dependency:unpack
>   goal to  extract the files to wherever you want them.

Comment: You are correct, but you misunderstood the issue. ChildA needs the filter.properties file from the resources of ChildB. To clarify, the process of attaching the filter.properties and unpacking does work during the maven build. The issue is around the error that Eclipse is throwing, which is a false negative.

Comment: Update #2 is plain wrong. Files are only shared between dependencies. I don't have a dependency between childA and childB. Again, the actual maven build process IS working. My issue is with the error Eclipse reports.

Comment: Update #3 correct that using relative paths for dependencies and modules is an anti-pattern. However, no where did I say I am using relative paths. I am attaching the filter.properties to artifact and unpacking during process-resources.